# How does "Cloud Files" from Rackspace know about my CNAME record?

Tags: cname-record, cdn, rackspace

**TLDR: when I make this DNS record:**

```
whatever.mydomain.com.  IN CNAME biglongjibberstring.r89.cf2.rackcdn.com.
```

**How does Rackspace know that this random host name I've chosen should go to my Cloud Files container/account as opposed to another customer?**

---

I just tested a simple example of using Cloud Files with Rackspace.  I made a Cloud Files "Container" and enabled the "Static Website" option.  I uploaded an example image and an example index.html file.  These files in this container are now available at this crazy-long URL, which the UI tells me I can use as the CNAME for my domain:

[image: Cloud Files container settings]

And sure enough, adding a CNAME record like:

whatever.mydomain.com.  IN CNAME biglongjibberstring.r89.cf2.rackcdn.com.

Browsing to http://whatever.mydomain.com/ works (tested the home page and the image).  But how could it possibly know that when it sees a request for "whatever.mydomain.com" (in the HTTP Host header) that it is meant for my particular cloud files container?

It seems to have something to do with DNS, since if I just put "blah.example.com" in my hosts file with the IP address that biglongjibberstring.r89.cf2.rackcdn.com. resolves to - that does not work (gives an error about Invalid URL - appears to be coming from Akamai).  The only way I could possibly see this working is if somehow the DNS lookup for whatever.mydomain.com was somehow transmitting back to Rackspace/Akamai DNS servers this relationship between "whatever.mydomain.com" and "biglongjibberstring.r89.cf2.rackcdn.com.".  But I've never seen this approach and I don't even think that DNS lookup that goes back to Rackspace/Akamai actually contains the information necessary for this (although I could be wrong about that).

Does anyone know what kind of black magic is going on here?

Comment: It's not black magic. It's protocol. Read: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7230#section-5.4

Comment: Right, but if the Host header contains "whatever.mydomain.com" and I've never typed this into my Rackspace Cloud Files control panel - how does it know that when it sees a request for "whatever.mydomain.com" it should go to my account and not someone else's?

Answer (score 1):

After observing the behavior, my best guess at what they could reasonably be doing is this:

When an HTTP request arrives at one of the CDN nodes and the request has an unknown `Host` header they themselves look up the name in the `Host` header.

If this name turns out to be a `CNAME` referring to a known name (on the form `<identifyinginformation>.rackcdn.com.`) they associate the name from the `Host` header with the appropriate resource, otherwise they return an error.

This is speculative but that's what I can think of that fits what is technically viable as well as the observed behavior. The [documentation at Rackspace](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/using-cnames-with-cloud-files-containers) does not specify how it actually works, but hopefully their support could help.

If anyone wants to experiment further on their own a Rackspace employee mentions the URL http://124f4d373d9886355285-0dddf6f52a326dca397d3ae1202a22fd.r49.cf2.rackcdn.com/1_logs_dir.png as an example in the comments at the documentation page linked above. Just add a `CNAME` to the host part of that URL, modify the URL accordingly and try it out.

Comment: I agree - I see no other way it would be workable.